# how do I handle External Exceptions in my code

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to capture image  on the count of a timer and save it **automatically** for which I have tried a code But an External Exception is been thrown when I run this code.And if i try to catch the exception the code runs but it doesn't save the captured image neither in the mentioned path nor anywhere else.
**Here picCap is the name of my pictureBox**

My code is,

```
    WebCam webcam;
    int duration = 0;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        duration++;
        textBox1.Text = duration.ToString();
        bool ischecked = radioButton2.Checked;

            if (duration <= 3)
            {
                radioButton2.Checked = true;
                if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
                {


                    picCap.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                   //External Exception not handled

                }
                else
                {
                    webcam.Stop();
                    timer1.Stop();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                radioButton2.Checked = false;
                //     radioButton3.Visible = false;
                radioButton3.Checked = true;

            }


    }
    //start
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        webcam.Start();
    }
    //stop
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        webcam.Stop();
    }

    private void mainWinForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webcam = new WebCam();
        webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref picCap);
    }
```

Extra details about the exception

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147467259
Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
Source=System.Drawing
ErrorCode=-2147467259
 StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at WindowsFormsApplication3.mainWinForm.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs:line 37
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
   at WebCam_Capture.WebCamCapture.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 InnerException:
```

Comment: It is the kind of exception you get when Image.Save() fails for any reason.  Usually related to having a problem with writing the file.  And writing one that has the exact same name as a directory will certainly always fail.

Comment: the location was not have the permission to store image..so it give error

Comment: What is `picCap`? What's the exception? We need details! Oh and btw. What do you want to happen here `picCap.Image = picCap.Image;`?

Comment: WebCam is a windw application form which has all the contents related to the start,stop & resolution configuration of the WebCam.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that picCap.Image = picCap.Image; it had nothing to do with this code. Well picCap is the name for the pictureBox

Comment: @Kutty Rajesh Valangai if the location doesn't have permissions then how should i get the permissions...Can u please guide me in this problem!!

Answer (score 2):

The exception indicates that the method requires a filename and not a folder path:

```
System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
```

It's likely failing because it can't save the file without the filename, so try adding one like the following example:

```
picCap.Image.Save(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyFilename.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```